# javascript counter increment is a bit wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, symfony-forms

I have the following javascript http://jsfiddle.net/847Kf/4/ that contains a counter at line 14 and 36. The code works but when i delete an item that i added and add a new item the counter continues from where it left.
For example: i insert 4 items 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 now i delete the second item and add a new item so i will have 1 , 3 , 4 , 5. How can i make that counter when i delete an item the counter should reset and redisplay the values according the example:
1, 3, 4, 5 - deleted an item and now the counter should change the values for the remaining item to: 1, 2, 3, 4.

HTML:

```
<ul class="tags" data-prototype="&lt;div&gt;&lt;label class=&quot; required&quot;&gt;__name__&lt;/label&gt;&lt;div id=&quot;task_tags___name__&quot;&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;label for=&quot;task_tags___name___name&quot; class=&quot; required&quot;&gt;Name&lt;/label&gt;&lt;input type=&quot;text&quot; id=&quot;task_tags___name___name&quot; name=&quot;task[tags][__name__][name]&quot; required=&quot;required&quot; maxlength=&quot;255&quot; /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;">
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
// setup an "add a tag" link
var $addTagLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_tag_link">Add a tag</a>');
var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addTagLink);

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Get the ul that holds the collection of tags
   var $collectionHolder = $('ul.tags');

    // add the "add a tag" anchor and li to the tags ul
    $collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);

    // count the current form inputs we have (e.g. 2), use that as the new
    // index when inserting a new item (e.g. 2)
    $collectionHolder.data('index', $collectionHolder.find(':input').length);

    $addTagLink.on('click', function(e) {
        // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
        e.preventDefault();

        // add a new tag form (see code block below)
        addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
    });


});

function addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {
    // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
    var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');

    // get the new index
    var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');

    // Replace '$$name$$' in the prototype's HTML to
    // instead be a number based on how many items we have
    var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

    // increase the index with one for the next item
    $collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);

    // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a tag" link li
    var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);

    // also add a remove button, just for this example
    $newFormLi.append('<a href="#" class="remove-tag">x</a>');

    $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);

    // handle the removal, just for this example
    $('.remove-tag').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).parent().remove();

        return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have so many `id`'s / `name`'s / `class`'s etc which incorporate the `index`. I would recommend regenerating the list on delete.

ie:-

```
function regenerateTagList(){
  var vals = $('.tags li.tag input').toArray().map(function(v, i) { return v.value; });
  $('.tags li.tag').remove();
  $('ul.tags').data('index', 0);
  for(var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++){
      addTagForm($('ul.tags'), $newLinkLi);
      $('.tags li.tag input:last').val(vals[i]);
  }
}
```

And add a class to the `li` for the tag so you can select them from the add link:-

```
var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>', { class:"tag" }).append(newForm);
```

then call after you remove:-

```
$('.remove-tag').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parent().remove();

    regenerateTagList();

    return false;
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/847Kf/242/)

Comment: It works just fine, also the other responses from here work but i've chosen  this one to use.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is on how you count the elements.
When creating a new tag, you update the quantity on the data, but it doesn't get noticed when deleting.
You have two options:

1. Update on the removal the value `$collectionHolder.data('index', index - 1)`
2. take the quantity on each creation, not setting it on `document ready`

I've noticed another issue with deleting. When you you create every element, you are attaching a delete event to every `.remove-tag` in the DOM, on the 3rd creation, the first element would have 3 events attached, and the 2nd two.
Two avoid that I'd do something like:

```js
$('ul.tags').on('click','.remove-tag',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

What that means is something like "Look on dom for ul.tag, and if a click event is triggered on a .remove-tag do this" so it keeps alive and active for the new tags created.

Answer (score 1):

This modification will do the change without regenerating the whole thing:

```
$('.remove-tag').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
    var count = 0;
    $('.tags li').each(function() {
        $(this).find('div label').first().text(count);
        count++;
    });
    return false;
});
```

It finds all the li's, then finds the first label in each li and changes it to the count variable.  It could be simplified if the first label had a class called 'count'.